# Как заставить multiselect отображаться при выборе?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Вот как это нужно:

[image: пример]

Вот как это есть у меня:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю где еще копать? Копался в Bootstrap multiselect но пока тщетно. Кто знает подскажите или покажите. Спасибо.

```
Код выложен `https://jsfiddle.net/yurzui/qwfc4htk/`
```

Comment: Выложите на jsfiddle, тогда может и народ подтянется, а так только обрывки кода...

Comment: А если повесить функции на события onchange для input'ов, которые будут изменять содержимое span.price-label?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yurzui/qwfc4htk пример кода

Comment: насчет повесить функции на события onchange для input'ов - не совсем понимаю как это сделать

Comment: Например, событие onchange добавленное к тегу <textarea> срабатывает каждый раз, когда введен новый текст и поле потеряло фокус(http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onchange).. Вот подкинул Вам идею http://jsfiddle.net/borodatych/rgz7d7yy/, требует немножко поработать напильником.

Comment: Благодарю за идею и за работу, огромное спасибо и можно еще вопрос, что добавить что бы эти данные отправлялись в форме?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как понял за место PRIJS нужно что бы отображали введенные данные ниже в инпутах?!

Ну и наворочено у Вас...
Вот идея для реализации:

```
<div id="PRIJS">
    <span id="st1">...</span> - <span id="st2">...</span>
</div>
<input type="text" id="stack1"/>
-
<input type="text" id="stack2"/>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#stack1').on('keydown', function(){
            $('#st1').text( $(this).val()||'...' );
        });
        $('#stack2').on('keydown', function(){
            $('#st2').text( $(this).val()||'...' );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Как приведете пример на **jsfiddle** ,будет более конструктивнее...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yurzui/qwfc4htk/ вот пример

Comment: Вижу только такой выход: http://jsfiddle.net/borodatych/rgz7d7yy/. *Придется причесать, подкинул как идею*.